# Disable customized context menu for some cases using python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, python-addin, context-menu

I create a python add-in tool to add new item to the context menu, but I want the new item enabled only when user right click on map when within a buffer of polyline feature. I haven't figure out how to make it, which means for the area qualified (within a buffer of polyline) can see the new item on context menu, others won't show the new item (or the new item is disabled in grey). I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and python.

Comment: Could you describe in a little more detail the user workflow here? What does your tool do currently? Do you have any relevant code you can share? I would also be concerned that setting a tool's enabled state based on geographic context may be too performance-draining, at least with arcpy.

Comment: Hi Blah238,  The workflow should be: (1) User select features on map (2) User right click the selected feature and the customized context menu appear. (3) for those objects not on the polyline(or polygon) cannot see the context. Since I am now in the design phase of a project, so I haven't start coding, just want to confirm everything is possible. thank you!

Comment: If these are requirements can you edit your question to include them, please?  My recommendation would be to introduce some proof of concept prototyping into your design phase.